# How can I make this .htaccess redirect exclude the home page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this setup:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

and

```
http://www2.example.com
```

I would like to redirect all pages from the first set, except the homepage, to the newer (www2) domain.

Here's what I have in my .htaccess now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www2.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www2.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This works, but I want to exclude the homepage. How can I add the additional condition for that?

**Edit:** Also, I would like to exclude a folder called "assets" and all of it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your regex to `.+`, which means *at least one or more of `.`*, where the `.` can be anything:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www2.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www2.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

The reasoning here is that the home page (request URI = `/`) will have the slash stripped and actually be an empty string, which `.*` matches. But if you have `.+`, the empty string (home page) won't match.

If the homepage is something other than just `/` (like, `/home.html`) then you can exclude it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home\.html
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www2.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www2.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works but it's actually redirecting my assets folder. I apologize, I should have been more specific. I also would like to exclude a folder called "assets" and all of it's content. So redirect everything, but home page and a folder at "/assets/*"

Comment: @envysea looks at the second option, the one with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home\.html`. If you want other URIs to be excluded, just add more of them, replacing `home\.html` with whatever you want excluded.

Comment: Hey Jon, I'm pinging you again to see if you could add to your answer since I'm still stuck and would like to close this. Everything should redirect but the home page (/ and index.html), a folder and its contents called assets, and a folder and its contents called images should redirect. Thanks